# angular redirect to backend app on same host

Tags: django, angular, nginx, redirect

I've got an app with Angular in the front end and Django in the backend on different ports on the same host, and for authentication, I have this piece of code in my userService.js:

```
authenticateUser: function() {
                  return $window.location.href = 'https://myhost:backend_port/oidc/auth/request/'
            },
```

but when I visit my app, it's giving me "cannot GET /oidc/auth/request/"
so I think the front end is trying to handle it when it should be going to the backend.

Do I need to add the 'location' in the Nginx config for the backend? Here's my current config:

```
    server {
    listen 9004;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/chained.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/key.key;
    error_page 497 https://$host:9004$request_uri;

    server_name myhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-9004.log error;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://myhost:3004;
    }

    location /static/ {
            root /path/to/backend/code;
    }

    location /media/ {
            root /path/to/media;
    }

    location /api {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/myapp.sock;
    }
```

***UPDATE:***

I tried adding the following to my nginx config:

```
   location /oidc {
           root /path/to/backend/code;
   }
```

and now I get a 404. But it should be covered by my urls.py:

```
# openid requirement
url(r'^oidc/', include('oidc_rp.urls')),
```

here is oidc_rp.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^auth/request/$', views.OIDCAuthRequestView.as_view(), name='oidc_auth_request'),
url(r'^auth/cb/$', views.OIDCAuthCallbackView.as_view(), name='oidc_auth_callback'),
url(r'^end-session/$', views.OIDCEndSessionView.as_view(), name='oidc_end_session'),
]
```

***UPDATE 2:***

the angular frontend is running on pm2

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a location block for /oidc, that part of routing should be handled by your django app. Can you post your full nginx conf file? Do you have different server blocks for both client and server ports? Also, I'd suggest not to post your actual fodler structure on public sites.

Comment: thanks for catching me on the folder structure :) The front end is running on pm2 so it's not in my nginx conf. Added the rest of the conf

Comment: 9004 is the frontend port here I think. What is you backend port? Do you have another nginx conf that listens on backend_port, or is the backend port accessible by public? Looking at the provided configuration only, you should be able to access the api like this:  https://myhost:9004/api/oidc/auth/request/ (https://myhost:9004/api/ is passed to django)

Comment: 9004 is the backend port, 3004 is the frontend port. let me try that